# Range Slider's thumb with text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Is it possible to make range slider (js or jQuery) with thumb's text inside?

Like this

[image: like this]

I tried with code below, but it's not working

```css
.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb::after: content='08:00-10:00'
```

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" step='25'>
```

Comment: It's not possible to do that with the standard HTML `range` input. You'd need to use a custom control.

Comment: I can see it looking OK for the user when the whole of the (extended) 'thumb' fits within the slider - though possibly something to indicate the middle of the thumb might be useful, but what do you want it to look like when the user it choosing a value towards one or other of the ends?

Answer (score 4):

You could create an element that would go on top of the range slider. I have an example where the `.range-text` element is the same size as the slider so it feels the same as the regular input when moving it, and the text/position updates via JS. Hopefully it gives you an idea of how you can create something to solve for your needs

```js
const rangeInput = document.querySelector('input[type="range"]');
const rangeText = document.querySelector('.range-text');

rangeInput.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  let newVal = e.target.value;
  let negNewVal = -1 * newVal;
  
  rangeText.style.left = (newVal + '%'); //Set range left position
  rangeText.style.transform = 'translate(' + negNewVal + '%, 2px)'; //Set range translate to correct
  rangeText.innerHTML = newVal; //Set range text equal to input position
})
```

```css
.input-container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}
input[type="range"] {
  appearance: none;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 0;
}
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -moz-appearance: none !important;
  appearance: none !important;
  position: relative;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
}
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-thumb {
  -moz-appearance: none !important;
  appearance: none !important;
  position: relative;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
}
.range-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: skyblue;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  transform: translate(0, 2px);
}
```

```html
<div class="input-container">
  <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" step='25'>
  <div class="range-text">0</div>
</div>
```